# smooch web messenger embedded mode no longer working?

Tags: smooch

I've updated the code for embedded mode according to the smooch documentation

https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/#styling-the-conversation-interface

On this page

https://www.vetchat.com.au/smooch/

But it is no longer working, just displays as default.

Has this error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at Object.render (web-messenger.js:88)
    at e.__onWebMessengerHostReady__ ((index):141)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (smooch.4.0.4.min.js:178)
    at e (bootstrap b9ab67f504327dcb9c27:19)
    at bootstrap b9ab67f504327dcb9c27:62
    at bootstrap b9ab67f504327dcb9c27:62
```

I'm not much of a dev, was hoping someone advise if i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of your page, it looks like the `init` part has some errors in it.

Currently, it's :

```
Smooch.init({appId: '<app-id>'});
embedded: true
Smooch.render(document.getElementById('chat-container'));
```

when it should be

```
Smooch.init({
    appId: '<app-id>',
    embedded: true
});

Smooch.render(document.getElementById('chat-container'));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For simplicity I have added the code to a plain html page  https://www.vetchat.com.au/smooch.html

Comment: I've also tried generating a new messenger app within smooch, same result

Comment: I just dug in the code and it's a bug. I'll work on a fix and let you know when it's released.

Comment: I just released a new version (4.0.5) and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Marc-Antoine Lemieux. Have retested and still get the same error

Comment: Based on the link you provided above, you are trying to render the Web Messenger inside element with id `chat-container` (`Smooch.render(document.getElementById('chat-container'))`) and there's no such element in the page.